# Facebook Messenger Platform: Greet user at Welcome Screen

Tags: facebook-messenger, x-facebook-platform

I would like to greet user when he started conversation with my page.
Something like: 'Hi Marian, How can I help?'.

[image]

It could be done with Send-to-Messenger Plugin as this plugin is sending authentication request to server. User id can be extracted and facebook api queried for firstName. It's just working fine.

The problem is user is clicks **Message** button directly on Facebook page. Then he clicks "Get Started" in message popup. Then default [welcome message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#welcome_message_configuration) is sent to him, but no authentication is sent to server, so I cannot sent personalized greeting as with Send-to-Messanger plugin.

Anybody any workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want send single message? You can send welcom message like "Welcome to XpessGo". After that you riceive delivery message. if the identifier matches to new user (you will not once he did not write), you can send a personalized message.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no pass through parameter sent with the Message Us plugin like there is with the Send to Messenger plugin. For people who enter through Message Us, you'll have to authenticate/account link through some other means like giving them a URL to a mobile login page.